# WPF - Can't use this.NavigationService.Navigate in a page that's in a Window

Tags: c#, wpf

I've loaded the Page1 inside a frame in a window and there is a button inside page1 that has this code:

```
 private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("NextPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

This is the frame within MainWindow:

```
<Grid>
    <Frame x:Name="Main" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" Margin="0 0 0 0" />
</Grid>
```

Here is where I load Page1:

```
 private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Main.Navigate(new Page1());
    }
```

It works when I eliminate the window and directly start the app with Page1, but I want to have the window because the one Visual Studio creates automatically looks really bad.
It throws the regular `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`  exception when I try to use it inside the page that is loaded to a frame of MainWindow.

So, how can i navigate between pages within a window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `Window.GetWindow` to get a reference to the parent window, cast the result to your window type and then access the `Frame`:

```
private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this) as MainWindow;
    if (parentWindow != null)
        parentWindow.Main.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("NextPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Yeah, this actually loads the page but I can't see it and Page1 is still there.

Comment: How can it load the page if you don't see it...?

Comment: I saw the code jumping to NextPage's `InitializeComponent()` function while debugging.

Comment: Do you have more than one `Frame` called "Main" then? Or are you displaying more than one window? Or navigating back to `Page1` after you have navigated to `NextPage`? You need to provide a reproducible example if you want any further help. You are obviously missing something here because the solution I showed is easy.

Comment: NVM got it. Thank you for your help. It works perfectly now.